# ZF3 FormElementManager: how to get ServiceManager

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I'm porting code from ZF2 to ZF3.

In ZF2 when I create a form via FormElementManager I can access the servicelocator on the init method and configure some stuff like this:

```
public function init()
{
    $this->serviceLocator = $this->getFormFactory()->getFormElementManager()->getServiceLocator();
    $this->translator = $this->serviceLocator->get('translator');
}
```

This is convenient in very large applications. In fact all my forms inherit from a BaseForm class.

In ZF3 this is bad pratic and serviceLocator are deprecated.
Which is the best way to get the same result ? 
One way is to inject every form in the ControllerFactory or ServiceFactory with the stuff needed but this is very tedious.

Any help is appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

First of, you should not have the ServiceManager and/or childs of it (like the FormElementManager) available in your Form objects.

Using the Factory pattern, you should create fully functional, stand-alone Form, Fieldset and InputFilter objects.

There will definitely be some tedious work, as you put it, but you need only do it once.

Let's say you want to create a Location. A Location consists of a `name` property and a OneToOne unidirectional `Address` reference. This creates the following needs:

- LocationForm (-InputFilter)
- LocationFieldset (-InputFilter)
- AddressFieldset (-InputFilter)
- Config for the above
- Factory for each of the 6 classes above

In this answer I'll mash everything down to bare minimums and use classes and examples from my own repositories, so for full code you can go [here](https://github.com/rkeet/zf-doctrine-form) and for examples [here](https://github.com/rkeet/zf-doctrine-form-examples).

After the creation of the classes themselves, I'll show you the config you need for this use case and the Factories which tie all of it together.

---

#### AbstractFieldset

```
abstract class AbstractFieldset extends Fieldset
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->add(
            [
                'name'     => 'id',
                'type'     => Hidden::class,
                'required' => false,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

#### AbstractInputFilter

```
abstract class AbstractFieldsetInputFilter extends AbstractInputFilter
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->add([
            'name' => 'id',
            'required' => false,
            'filters' => [
                ['name' => ToInt::class],
            ],
            'validators' => [
                ['name' => IsInt::class],
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

#### AddressFieldset

```
class AddressFieldset extends AbstractFieldset
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'street',
            'required' => true,
            'type' => Text::class,
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Address',
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

#### AddressInputFilter

```
class AddressFieldsetInputFilter extends AbstractFieldsetInputFilter
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'street',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => [
                ['name' => StringTrim::class],
                ['name' => StripTags::class],
                [
                    'name' => ToNull::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'type' => ToNull::TYPE_STRING,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'validators' => [
                [
                    'name' => StringLength::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'min' => 3,
                        'max' => 255,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

---

So far, easy. Now, we need to create the LocationFieldset and LocationFieldsetInputFilter. These will make use of the Address(-Fieldset) classes.

#### LocationFieldset

```
class LocationFieldset extends AbstractFieldset
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'name',
            'required' => true,
            'type' => Text::class,
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Name',
            ],
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'type' => AddressFieldset::class,
            'name' => 'address',
            'required' => true,
            'options' => [
                'use_as_base_fieldset' => false,
                'label' => 'Address',
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

#### LocationFieldsetInputFilter

```
class LocationFieldsetInputFilter extends AbstractFieldsetInputFilter
{
    /**
     * @var AddressFieldsetInputFilter
     */
    protected $addressFieldsetInputFilter;

    public function __construct(AddressFieldsetInputFilter $addressFieldsetInputFilter) 
    {
        $this->addressFieldsetInputFilter = $addressFieldsetInputFilter;
    }

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->add($this->addressFieldsetInputFilter, 'address');

        $this->add(
            [
                'name'       => 'name',
                'required'   => true,
                'filters'    => [
                    ['name' => StringTrim::class],
                    ['name' => StripTags::class],
                    [
                        'name'    => ToNull::class,
                        'options' => [
                            'type' => ToNull::TYPE_STRING,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'validators' => [
                    [
                        'name'    => StringLength::class,
                        'options' => [
                            'min' => 3,
                            'max' => 255,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

---

Ok, so that's not very exciting yet. Do note, the LocationFieldset uses the AddressFieldset as a type. Instead, in the InputFilter class a full fledged class object (an InputFilter instance) is expected.

So, the Form. I also use an AbstractForm (BaseForm in your case) to handle a few defaults. In my complete one (in linked repo), there's a bit more, but for here this'll suffice. This adds CSRF protection to the Form and adds a submit button if the form does not have one. This only gets done if the Form class does not have either one when you call the init, so you can override these settings.

#### AbstractForm

```
abstract class AbstractForm extends \Zend\Form\Form implements InputFilterAwareInterface
{
    protected $csrfTimeout = 900; // 15 minutes

    public function __construct($name = null, $options = [])
    {
        $csrfName = null;
        if (isset($options['csrfCorrector'])) {
            $csrfName = $options['csrfCorrector'];
            unset($options['csrfCorrector']);
        }

        parent::__construct($name, $options);

        if ($csrfName === null) {
            $csrfName = 'csrf';
        }

        $this->addElementCsrf($csrfName);
    }

    public function init()
    {
        if (!$this->has('submit')) {
            $this->addSubmitButton();
        }
    }

    public function addSubmitButton($value = 'Save', array $classes = null)
    {
        $this->add([
            'name'       => 'submit',
            'type'       => Submit::class,
            'attributes' => [
                'value' => $value,
                'class' => (!is_null($classes) ? join (' ', $classes) : 'btn btn-primary'),
            ],
        ]);
    }

    public function get($elementOrFieldset)
    {
        if ($elementOrFieldset === 'csrf') {
            // Find CSRF element
            foreach ($this->elements as $formElement) {
                if ($formElement instanceof Csrf) {
                    return $formElement;
                }
            }
        }

        return parent::get($elementOrFieldset);
    }

    protected function addElementCsrf($csrfName = 'csrf')
    {
        $this->add([
            'type'    => Csrf::class,
            'name'    => 'csrf',
            'options' => [
                'csrf_options' => [
                    'timeout' => $this->csrfTimeout,
                ],
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

#### LocationForm

```
class LocationForm extends AbstractForm
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->add([
            'name' => 'location',
            'type' => LocationFieldset::class,
            'options' => [
                'use_as_base_fieldset' => true,
            ],
        ]);

        parent::init();
    }
}
```

---

Now we have everything to make the Form. We still need the validation. Let's create these now:

#### AddressFieldsetInputFilter

```
class AddressFieldsetInputFilter extends AbstractFieldsetInputFilter
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'street',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => [
                ['name' => StringTrim::class],
                ['name' => StripTags::class],
                [
                    'name' => ToNull::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'type' => ToNull::TYPE_STRING,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'validators' => [
                [
                    'name' => StringLength::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'min' => 3,
                        'max' => 255,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

#### LocationFieldsetInputFilter

```
class LocationFieldsetInputFilter extends AbstractFieldsetInputFilter
{
    protected $addressFieldsetInputFilter;

    public function __construct(AddressFieldsetInputFilter $addressFieldsetInputFilter) 
    {
        $this->addressFieldsetInputFilter = $addressFieldsetInputFilter;
    }

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->add($this->addressFieldsetInputFilter, 'address');

        $this->add(
            [
                'name'       => 'name',
                'required'   => true,
                'filters'    => [
                    ['name' => StringTrim::class],
                    ['name' => StripTags::class],
                    [
                        'name'    => ToNull::class,
                        'options' => [
                            'type' => ToNull::TYPE_STRING,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'validators' => [
                    [
                        'name'    => StringLength::class,
                        'options' => [
                            'min' => 3,
                            'max' => 255,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

#### LocationFormInputFilter

```
class LocationFormInputFilter extends AbstractFormInputFilter
{
    /** @var LocationFieldsetInputFilter  */
    protected $locationFieldsetInputFilter;

    public function __construct(LocationFieldsetInputFilter $filter) 
    {
        $this->locationFieldsetInputFilter = $filter
    }

    public function init()
    {
        $this->add($this->locationFieldsetInputFilter, 'location');

        parent::init();
    }
}
```

---

Right, that's all of the classes themselves. Do you see how they'll be nested together? This creates re-usable components, which is why I said you'll need to do this only once. Next time you need an Address or a Location, you just make sure to load the AddressFieldset and set the InputFilter in the Factory. The latter, setting the right InputFilter, is done via Setter Injection the Factories. Shown below.

---

#### AbstractFieldsetFactory

```
abstract class AbstractFieldsetFactory implements FactoryInterface
{

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $fieldset;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $fieldsetName;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $fieldsetObject;

    public function __construct($fieldset, $name, $fieldsetObject)
    {
        $this->fieldset = $fieldset;
        $this->fieldsetName = $name;
        $this->fieldsetObject = $fieldsetObject;

        $this->hydrator = new Reflection(); // Replace this with your own preference, either Reflection of ZF or maybe the Doctrine EntityManager...
    }

    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $fieldset = $this->fieldset;
        $fieldsetObject = $this->fieldsetObject;

        /** @var AbstractFieldset $fieldset */
        $fieldset = new $fieldset($this->hydrator, $this->name ?: $this->fieldsetName);
        $fieldset->setHydrator(
            new DoctrineObject($this->hydrator)
        );
        $fieldset->setObject(new $fieldsetObject());

        return $fieldset;
    }
}
```

#### AddressFieldsetFactory

```
class AddressFieldsetFactory extends AbstractFieldsetFactory
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(AddressFieldset::class, 'address', Address::class);
    }
}
```

#### LocationFieldsetFactory

```
class LocationFieldsetFactory extends AbstractFieldsetFactory
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(LocationFieldset::class, 'location', Location::class);
    }
}
```

---

#### AbstractFieldsetInputFilterFactory

```
abstract class AbstractFieldsetInputFilterFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    protected $container;

    /**
     * @var HydratorInterface
     */
    protected $hydrator;

    /**
     * @var InputFilterPluginManager
     */
    protected $inputFilterManager;

    /**
     * Use this function to setup the basic requirements commonly reused.
     *
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     * @param string|null $className
     * @throws \Psr\Container\ContainerExceptionInterface
     * @throws \Psr\Container\NotFoundExceptionInterface
     */
    public function setupRequirements(ContainerInterface $container, $className = null)
    {
        $this->inputFilterManager = $container->get(InputFilterPluginManager::class);
    }
}
```

#### AddressFieldsetInputFilterFactory

```
class AddressFieldsetInputFilterFactory extends AbstractFieldsetInputFilterFactory
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        parent::setupRequirements($container, Address::class);

        return new AddressFieldsetInputFilter($this->hydrator);
    }
}
```

#### LocationFieldsetInputFilterFactory

```
class LocationFieldsetInputFilterFactory extends AbstractFieldsetInputFilterFactory
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        parent::setupRequirements($container, Location::class);

        /** @var AddressFieldsetInputFilter $addressFieldsetInputFilter */
        $addressFieldsetInputFilter = $this->inputFilterManager->get(AddressFieldsetInputFilter::class);

        return new LocationFieldsetInputFilter(
            $addressFieldsetInputFilter,
            $this->hydrator
        );
    }
}
```

---

That takes care of the FieldsetInputFilterFactory classes. Just the Form left.

In my case I use the same abstract factory class as for the Fieldset classes.

---

#### LocationFormInputFilterFactory

```
class LocationFormInputFilterFactory extends AbstractFieldsetInputFilterFactory
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        parent::setupRequirements($container);

        /** @var LocationFieldsetInputFilter $locationFieldsetInputFilter */
        $locationFieldsetInputFilter = $this->getInputFilterManager()->get(LocationFieldsetInputFilter::class);

        return new LocationFormInputFilter(
            $locationFieldsetInputFilter,
            $this->hydrator
        );
    }
}
```

---

So, that's all of the classes done. It's a complete setup. You might encounter some bugs as I modified my own code to remove getters/setters, code comments/hinting, error, property and variable checking without testing. But it should work ;)

However, we're nearly done. We still need:

- config
- usage in a Controller
- print/use Form in a View

---

The config is easy:

```
'form_elements' => [
    'factories' => [
        AddressFieldset::class  => AddressFieldsetFactory::class,
        LocationFieldset::class => LocationFieldsetFactory::class,
        LocationForm::class     => LocationFormFactory::class,
    ],
],
'input_filters' => [
    'factories' => [
        AddressFieldsetInputFilter::class  => AddressFieldsetInputFilterFactory::class,
        LocationFieldsetInputFilter::class => LocationFieldsetInputFilterFactory::class,
        LocationFormInputFilter::class     => LocationFormInputFilterFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

That's it. That little bit ties all of the above classes together.

---

To get the Form into a Controller, you would do something like this in the Factory:

```
class EditControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $hydrator = new Reflection(); // or $container->get('hydrator') or $container->get(EntityManager::class), or whatever you use

        /** @var FormElementManagerV3Polyfill $formElementManager */
        $formElementManager = $container->get('FormElementManager');

        /** @var LocationForm $form */
        $form = $formElementManager->get(LocationForm::class); // See :) Easy, and re-usable

        return new EditController($hydrator, $form);
    }
}
```

A typical "Edit" action would be like this (mind, this one uses Doctrine's EntityManager as the hydrator):

```
public function editAction()
{
    $id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id', null);

    /** @var Location $entity */
    $entity = $this->getObjectManager()->getRepository(Location::class)->find($id);

    /** @var LocationForm $form */
    $form = $this->form;
    $form->bind($entity);

    /** @var Request $request */
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            /** @var Location $object */
            $object = $form->getObject();

            $this->getObjectManager()->persist($object);

            try {
                $this->getObjectManager()->flush();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // exception handling
            }

            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('route/name', ['id' => $object->getId()]);
        }
    }

    return [
        'form'               => $form,
        'validationMessages' => $form->getMessages() ?: '',
    ];
}
```

And the View Partial would look like this (based on the `return` in the above action):

form($form) ?>

---

So, that's it. Fully fledged, re-usable classes. Single setup. And in the end just a single line in the Factory for the Controller.

Please take note though:

- Form, Fieldset and InputFilter use "address" input name. Very important to keep these the same throughout as Zend does some magic based on the names to match Fieldset with InputFilter.

---

If you have any more questions about how this works, please read through the documentation in the repo's I linked first, before asking below this question. There's more there that should help you out more, for example for Collection handling.

Comment: I will try your approach, following your projects.
I have developed in the past my own system to auto generate forms directly from doctrine entities. It work well for my scope but it is more more simple and the approach is different. Thanks for sharing.